# How to implement instant messaging Application in android

Tags: android, socket.io, instant-messaging

I am working on an instant messaging android application . I have successfully implemented the chat between my application and web application .I have used  `compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.6.2'` library to implement this. But when i installed the same app on another mobile phone, device to device communication did not work. I think i am missing something here. What i have to implement in my app now. Broadcast Receiver or GCM(Google Cloud Messaging). My code is as below:

**1. ChatActivity.java**

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity {
public static final String TAG = ChatActivity.class.getSimpleName();
EditText edMessage;
Button sendMessage;
private Socket mSocket;
String sID, lID, md5StringRoomID, message, friendName, loggedInUser;
String frndID;
int smallerID, largerID;
AlmaChatDatabase almaChatDatabase;
// Chat messages list adapter
private MessagesListAdapter adapter;
private List<Message> listMessages;
private ListView listViewMessages;
boolean isSelf = false; // to check whether the message is owned by you or not.true means message is owned by you .
Message msg;
int loggedInUserID;
private String URL_FEED_Message = "";
APIConfiguration apiConfiguration;

{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
        Log.e("Socket", String.valueOf(mSocket));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    sendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendMessage);
    almaChatDatabase = new AlmaChatDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    loggedInUserID = almaChatDatabase.getUserID(); // Getting ID of the Logged in user from the database
    Log.e("UserID", "Id of Logged in user  " + loggedInUserID);

    listMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    adapter = new MessagesListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listMessages);
    listViewMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_messages);
    listViewMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Getting the ID of the friend from the previous screen using getExtras
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    frndID = bundle.getString("ID");
    Log.e("FriendID", frndID);
    final int friendID = Integer.parseInt(frndID);
    friendName = bundle.getString("name");
    Log.e("FriendName", friendName);
    loggedInUser = almaChatDatabase.getUserName(); // Name of logged in user
    Log.e("LoggedInUser", loggedInUser);
    // Converting first lowercase letter of every word in Uppercase
    final String loggedInUpper = upperCase(loggedInUser);
    //To find the current time
    Date d = new Date();
    final long time = d.getTime();
    // Comparing the loggedInUserId and friendID
    if (friendID < loggedInUserID) {
        smallerID = friendID;
        largerID = loggedInUserID;
    } else {
        smallerID = loggedInUserID;
        largerID = friendID;
    }
    sID = String.valueOf(smallerID);
    lID = String.valueOf(largerID);
    String combinedID = sID + lID;
    Log.e("combined ID", combinedID);
    md5StringRoomID = convertPassMd5(combinedID); // Encrypting the combinedID to generate Room ID
    Log.e("md5StringRoomID", md5StringRoomID);

    // Using the API for loading old chat messages
    apiConfiguration = new APIConfiguration();
    String api_message = apiConfiguration.getApi_message(); // Getting the API of messages
    URL_FEED_Message = api_message + md5StringRoomID; // md5String is the encrypted room ID here
    Log.e("URL_FEED_MESSAGE", URL_FEED_Message);

    Log.e("Network request", "Fresh Request");
    // We first check for cached request
    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED_Message);
    if (entry != null) {
        // fetch the data from cache
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFeed(new JSONArray(data));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_FEED_Message, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                Log.e("JsonArray", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
                if (jsonArray != null) {
                    parseJsonFeed(jsonArray);
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.e("ErrorResponse", String.valueOf(volleyError));
            }
        }
        );
        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    }


    edMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMessage);
    //Listening on Events
    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectionError);
    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
    mSocket.on("send:notice", onReceive); // Listening event for receiving messages
    mSocket.connect(); // Explicitly call connect method to establish connection here
    mSocket.emit("subscribe", md5StringRoomID);

    sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //mSocket.emit("subscribe", md5String);
            message = edMessage.getText().toString().trim();
            Log.e("message", message);
            if (!message.equals("")) {
                edMessage.setText(" ");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("room_id", md5StringRoomID);
                    jsonObject.put("user", loggedInUpper);
                    jsonObject.put("id", friendID);
                    jsonObject.put("message", message);
                    jsonObject.put("date", time);
                    jsonObject.put("status", "sent");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                isSelf = true; // Boolean isSelf is set to be true as sender of the message is logged in user i.e. you
                attemptToSend(loggedInUpper, message, isSelf);
                mSocket.emit("send", jsonObject); // owner i.e LoggedIn user is sending the message
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter some text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });

}

//Adding message in the arrayList
public void attemptToSend(String senderName, String message, boolean isSelf) {
    msg = new Message(senderName, message, isSelf);
    listMessages.add(msg);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    playBeep();
}

// Playing sound when the message is sent by the owner
public void playBeep() {
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// encrypting string into MD5
public static String convertPassMd5(String pass) {
    String password = null;
    MessageDigest mdEnc;
    try {
        mdEnc = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        mdEnc.update(pass.getBytes(), 0, pass.length());
        pass = new BigInteger(1, mdEnc.digest()).toString(16);
        while (pass.length() < 32) {
            pass = "0" + pass;
        }
        password = pass;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return password;
}

// Converting first lowercase letter of every word in Uppercase
String upperCase(String source) {
    StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
    String[] strArr = source.split(" ");
    for (String str : strArr) {
        char[] stringArray = str.trim().toCharArray();
        stringArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(stringArray[0]);
        str = new String(stringArray);
        res.append(str).append(" ");
    }
    return res.toString().trim();
}

// Event Listeners
private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.e("Socket", "Connected");
    }
};


private Emitter.Listener onConnectionError = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.e("Error", "Error in connecting server");
    }
};
private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.e("Disconnect", "Socket Disconnected");
    }
};

// Event Listener for receiving messages
private Emitter.Listener onReceive = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        Log.e("Receive", "Message received");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                Log.e("DATA", String.valueOf(data));
                try {
                    JSONArray ops = data.getJSONArray("ops");
                    for (int i = 0; i < ops.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = ops.getJSONObject(i);
                        String roomID = object.getString("room_id");
                        Log.e("RoomID", roomID); // Getting room ID from JSON array
                        Log.e("Md5RoomID", md5StringRoomID); // Getting room id which we have created using logged in user ID and room id of the user through which chat has to be done
                        //Comparing the room IDs
                        if (md5StringRoomID.equals(roomID)) {
                            String senderName = object.getString("user");
                            Log.e("Sender Name", senderName);
                            String senderID = object.getString("id");
                            Log.e("SenderID", senderID);
                            JSONObject message = object.getJSONObject("message");
                            String messageReceived = message.getString("text");
                            Log.e("Message Received", messageReceived);
                            String loggedInUSerNAme = almaChatDatabase.getUserName();
                            //If the message is sent by the owner to other from webapp ,then we need to check whether the sender is the loggedinUSer in the App or not and we will right align the messages .
                            if (loggedInUSerNAme.equalsIgnoreCase(senderName)) {
                                isSelf = true;
                                msg = new Message(senderName, messageReceived, isSelf);
                                listMessages.add(msg);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                playBeep();
                            } else {
                                isSelf = false;
                                msg = new Message(senderName, messageReceived, isSelf);
                                listMessages.add(msg);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                playBeep();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Playing sound when the message is sent by other
    public void playBeep() {
        try {
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

};

// Parsing JSon Array which corresponds to the old chat messages
public void parseJsonFeed(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String roomID = jsonObject.getString("room_id");
            Log.e("RoomID", roomID);
            Log.e("Md5RoomID", md5StringRoomID);
            // If Room ID(created using id of logged in user and id of friend) matches with the room id obtained from JSON String
            if (md5StringRoomID.equals(roomID)) {
                String userName = jsonObject.getString("user");
                Log.e("Name", userName);
                String loggedInUSerNAme = almaChatDatabase.getUserName();
                Log.e("LoggedInUSer", loggedInUSerNAme);
                //If the message is sent by the owner to other from webapp ,then we need to check whether the sender is the loggedinUSer in the App or not and we will right align the messages .
                if (loggedInUSerNAme.equalsIgnoreCase(userName)) {
                    String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                    Log.e("message", message);
                    isSelf = true;
                    msg = new Message(userName, message, isSelf);
                    listMessages.add(msg);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //playBeep();
                } else {
                    JSONObject jsonMessage = jsonObject.getJSONObject("message");
                    String message = jsonMessage.getString("text");
                    isSelf = false;
                    msg = new Message(userName, message, isSelf);
                    listMessages.add(msg);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    // playBeep();
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // notify data changes to list adapter
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

**2.Constants.java**

```
public class Constants {

public static final String CHAT_SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.2.250:3000/";
```

}

Everything is working her except device to device communication. I am able to send messages from my app to web app and also receiving messages from web App. But device to device communication is not working. Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: what is Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL set to? I guess this is a client/server topology? during device/device communications, can you see the messages from both parties on the server? 
Could you post an example of the logs from the debug information you are outputting from the code above?

Comment: btw, you are using Log.e exclusively in your code, which is for errors. You could/should use Log.i for information output

Comment: @LintfordPickle : I am using an API to load the old messages.All the messages are stored on the server .e.g if a user A is sending message "Hello" to user B ,it will be displayed in the android app of user A and in the web app but not in the android app of user B.That is the main problem.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Are you using GCM?

Comment: @JaniBela : Yes i have fixed the issue.I am using socket.io-client library.I am not using GCM.

Comment: @DeepakR just let me ask a simple question because I am about to implement a similar one into my app :) Do you store those messages also for later use? So, If I come back to the activity can you load back the previuos messages and continue chatting?

Comment: @JaniBela: Yes i am storing the chat messages in MySQL database. Back-end developer is storing the chat messages in the database.He has provided me an API by using which i a loading the old messages in the ChatActivity.

Comment: @DeepakR Thank you for your help! Does this mean that when a message is sent then it goes right away to the mysql database and also goes to another phone at the same time using the socket-io library?

Comment: @JaniBela:My pleasure to help you.Backed Developer has used node.js .He is listening to socket and storing the data into database .At the same time ,i am using listener in my JAVA code,that is helping me to retrieve the message instantly.So when i need old messages ,i have to fetch them from the database.Any more help required?